# SQL renaming and using a Foreign Key reference

Tags: mysql

Is what I'm trying to do here correct? Can I rename the foreign key in the table?

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
    (
    EMP_NUMBER INTEGER(25) NOT NULL,
    EMP_FIRST_NAME CHAR(60),
    EMP_LAST_NAME CHAR(60),
    EMP_SALARY DECIMAL (15,2),
    EMP_STARTDATE DATE,
    EMP_GENDER CHAR(1),
    EMP_HOURS INT(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(EMP_NUMBER)
    )

    CREATE TABLE ORDERS
    ( ORDER_NUMBER INTEGER(45) NOT NULL,
    ORDER_PART_NAME CHAR(150),
    ORDER_PLACED_BY INTEGER(50)

    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUMBER),
    FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_PLACED_BY) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_NUMBER) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
```

**FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_PLACED_BY) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_NUMBER) ON UPDATE CASCADE** ?

Does this work? Can EMP_NUMBER exist in two different tables without error?

```
    CREATE TABLE ORDERS
    ( ORDER_NUMBER INTEGER(45) NOT NULL,
    ORDER_PART_NAME CHAR(150),
    EMP_NUMBER INTEGER(25),

    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUMBER),
    FOREIGN KEY (EMP_NUMBER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
```

It's probably a very simple question, just trying to learn this stuff all by myself and so far this is the big question for me, because then I'd have to remake all my tables. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can but it will have to be scoped by it's table name while querying like `orders.EMP_NUMBER` if you are joining with table `EMPLOYEE` since that table as well have a column with same name.

Again to point out, in your `ORDERS` table FK constraint definition is wrong. It has to be

```
FOREIGN KEY (EMP_NUMBER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_NUMBER) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```